# Forcing transparency on layers below

Tags: gimp, layers, transparency

I am pretty new at Gimp, so not sure if this is possible at all.

Let's say I have two lines like this, and I give the impression one line is on top of the other by clipping at the intersection, like this:

[image: cross]

Now let's say those two lines are in different layers and I want this "clipping" to basically be transparent (not just white), is it possible to do something in the layer of the line on top to force transparency in the layer below?

I tried to play with layer masks, but did not have any luck...

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create two shapes, one would be your top line, and the other would be the "transparency" (another bigger line underneath it that is a mask on the lower line. Then link those two layers together, so if you move the top line, you'll mvoe the transparent mask around as well. Not sure if this is entirely possible in GIMP as I've never used it, but maybe it'll give you a creative idea!

There's a few downfalls to this solution, but it's the bets thing I can think of right now. I'm curious to see what other answers to this question may be!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea... I am just not able to have one layer ("transparency") to change the alpha channel of what's below... tried all the different layer modes, that does not help either... still looking... thanks for the help!